# Factory resetting repeatedly

Tags: factory-reset

> I did the factory resetting of my galaxy grand repeatedly (2-3 times) due to hang- up problems.  Is it possible to recover the data which were in the phone memory before first resetting?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

And the long answer is nooooooooooo.

But in a more serious tone, really, the answer is no. A factory reset resets the device to its factory state, as in before you owned the device and it still had that factory fresh smell. Unless you made backups of your files and applications, you will need to re-download/reacquire your information manually.